# Ionic adding additional access control allow origin to response headers

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, cors

**Ionic/Angular adding additional access control allow origin to response headers. How to prevent this?**

My Nginx server has CORS enabled

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

With my ionic http code using Angular HttpClient

```
const req = this.http.get('https://example.com/apiRequest');
```

When accessing the api get call on the browser, the response headers are normal

[image: Browser response headers on api call]

However, when using ionic serve, I get 2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, one is localhost:8100 and the other is '*' which was added. This issue also occurs on Ios Simulator, android phone/simulator.

[image: Response headers on browser localhost:8100]

My guess is that Ionic/Angular is doing something, but I just don't know what. I don't own the nginx server so I can only ask through support about headers being added.

Has this issue occurred for anyone else? I don't think adding Ionic proxies would resolve this issue since I'm using a production website and tested it on a physical android device and the same issue occurs.

Or is this actually an Nginx error?

**EDIT**

After removing add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always; from nginx, I'm still getting access-control-allow-origin set as localhost.

I also have these headers, do they automatically add my request header origin to the response header?

vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Origin

origin: http://localhost:4200
referer: http://localhost:4200/

[image: Updated details for headers]

**Request headers**

```
    Accept
    application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
    keep-alive
Host
    example.com
Origin
    http://localhost:4200
Referer
    http://localhost:4200/tabs/home
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/80.0
```

**Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 5.3.2**
**@angular/cli :9.1.12**

Comment: did you add `withCredentials` in your request header?

Comment: No, I haven't added anything addition to Angular HttpClient at all, just using the get call.

Comment: can you try this out. Here Initiate Header object over.
`let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'withCredentials': 'true'
    });` 
And then send that header with our request
`this.http.get(url, { headers: headers })`

Comment: Tried that, doesn't do anything, still have double access-control-allow-origin in the response header

Comment: can you add your request header?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic/Angular is **not** adding any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header because it is a response header generally sent by a web server.

If you don't have control over the server, then it is advised to use **[HTTP Advance](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)** plugin for making http requests. This plugin makes use of native libraries for http requests, thus no CORS policy is enforced.

**A Brief about CORS in Ionic:**
Cross Origin Resource Sharing is policy enforced by web browsers mainly to protect user's data and prevent attacks that would compromise your app.

**In ionic 3, we didn't had to deal with CORS errors because our application was served with file:// origin. But with newer versions & upgrades to webview, our application is served on localhost:// or ionic://**

1. When your application request a web server, the underlying Webview verifies the requests made to different origin. i.e. other than localhost.
2. This verification is done by sending a Preflight request. In simpler words, the webview asks the server that a user at "localhost" is trying to access one of your resources, should I allow it?
3. If the server responds with right CORS headers in response to the Preflight request, webview then makes the actual GET/POST/PUT requests.